# Inference rule on LaTeX

Tags: overleaf, logic

[image: Just an inference rule]

Hi! I’m new to LaTeX and I’ve been trying to accomplish the inference rule that I show in the picture. Can someone help me do it? Not the demonstration, I want the code for the inference rule in my document, but I truly don’t know how to do it. I would highly appreciate anyone who helps me.

Comment: Did you see the `prftree` package? Or `ebproofs`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @egreg Thank youu very much, ill try :D

Comment: @Mensch thankkk youuuu!! :p

Comment: `bussproofs` and `bussproofs-extra` also serve such proofs.

Comment: See https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/.